# CouchDB _attachments adding fields to each attacment

Tags: couchdb

Is it possible to add fields to an element of an attachment.

For example I have a photo gallery made up of several images, which have been uploaded into the _attachments field of a page/record.

I want to add a description and a notes field to each picture.

Can anyone advise as to whether that is possible.  I have not been able to work out how to do it with Futon, as clicking the element just displays the image.

Thanks mcl

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to add custom data to the _attachments object. You can use a different object to store extra data, though.

e.g;

```
"_attachments": {
   "foo.txt": {
     ... CouchDB properties ...
   }
},
"attachments": {
   "foo.txt": {
     ... custom properties ...
   }
}
```